# BPY python change input unit from meter to centimeter

Tags: python, units

When using python bpy I can change the default "view" units to cm:

```
bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.length_unit = 'CENTIMETERS'
```

However, all the input is still in meters. For example if I change the camera location to:

```
cam.location = [0, 0, 5]
```

Blender thinks it's 5 meters ie 500 centimeters and not 5 centimeters.

[image]

How can I change the "bpy" settings to understand I'm using centimeters?

Comment: I think it's not possible, you can just use `0.05`

Comment: Thanks for the input @Karan - looking for a more permanent solution though, as this will get annoying with 100+ objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unit_settings.scale_length` [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UnitSettings.html#bpy.types.UnitSettings.scale_length) to convert between blender units and dimensions.

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.01
bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.length_unit = 'CENTIMETERS' 
cam = bpy.context.object
cam.location = [0, 0, 5]
```

[image]